# How could Dalmatian "anca" derive from Latin "hanc hodie"?

Tags: etymology, vulgar-latin

The semantic derivation from *hanc hodie* "this here day" to "also", "even" etc. does make no sense to me. The editor who added the etymology to [wiki/anca](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anca#dalmatian) and a many other languages, that share this idiom, wasn't very careful at least when formatting the entry (Edit: so that I totally missed the supposed connection to *hanc hodie*, but this does not change the question).

The reason I'm asking is, actually, Turkish *[ancak](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ancak)* "only, best; **but**", which as a conjunction reminds more of *anca*; or Persian *inja, [anja](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%A2%D9%86%D8%AC%D8%A7#Persian)* "here, there". I sceptically doubt the Latin etymology, because what's broadly labled as Persian, that came to be identified with e.g. Ossetian, had been active west of the Black See. It would be nice to have *that* ruled out. But of course that has little to do with Latin or Greek, probably.

Since the sound change--which might be regular, that is the lack of *h*--is presented, one has to wonder two questions: First, whether vulgar Latin had this; Second; if it was ever there in the first place. It would be easier to follow the root in *an-ja*.

It's understandable that a word meaning *here, there, then*, etc could come to be used as conjunction, but that's a bit slim. Is it etymologically sound, as far as Latin or vulgar Latin is concerned?

Comment: You should check the etymology info of the most obvious cognate, that being the Italian *anche*.

Comment: Well that doesn't explain much. How could *hanc hodie* - that is *this here today* if I understand correctly - or the alternative with *ora* come to mean *also, even*? I understand that some female noun is needed for the inflection to make sense (*die* "*m* or *f*" is another can of worms).

Comment: Check http://www.etimo.it/?term=anche (I do not understand Italian).

Comment: What do you think of _ancora_?

Comment: @draconis, since I had checked a bunch of different spellings when I couldn't find Turkish *ancas* (because it actually is *amcas* "cops"), I have to say, my thought is *anchored* in the east, so to speak. Now, I wouldn't mention Parthian ʾnjʾr‎ "(anjār), “behaviour”" if it doesn't readily give "vice squad", though it derives Persian هنجار "(hanjār) way, rule, law; habit, custom; norm", and it is akin to Sanskr. *sam-cara* "path" (? cp *sam-sara*?); But I find *even* and the like related to straight eveness in similiar idioms (Ger *glatt, gerade, eben, just …*), as for roads, *anyway*.

Comment: …I'm not sure I followed any of that. _Ancora_ is Italian for "still, even, yet, again, more" and seems to come from _hanc hōram_ "(during) this hour"; we see the same formation in other Romance languages (French _encore_, Occitan _encara_) with all the expected sound changes for a native word, so it presumably developed within Vulgar Latin.

Comment: @draconis, there's a second, more pertinent part to the comment, which I didn't finish: Also cp Ger *sogar* "even, actually, in fact". I find it difficult even for a native speakers to define such particles and other discourse markers. So they might be prone for corruption. Ger *jeh* "ever" is surely one candidate for a cognate with *hora*, as in *je-doch*, "although, however". I hold that it played into concessive usage of *ja* "yes" and *gar* (regionally *jar*, lenited *jah*; otherwise its stem means "cook, finish"), eg *Er hat ja/nu/so gar keine Ahnung* "He doesn't even have a clue"

Comment: That doesn't explain my thoughts much better, I'm sorry. *To anchor* should be a clear allusion to *be still*, I thought that was clear, and it is admittedly a bit of a joke, that is supposed to hint at borrowing across the mare nostrum. The part about *sam-cara* is feeble minded, riffing more on *even* than the other glosses; which appears degenerate because I'm not familiar with *anca* itself--that's the very reason I'm asking; It's notable of the German glosses that I mentioned, three also mean "just now" and "straight".

Comment: And if it didn't become clear before, then the third part about *gar* should imply that I suppose an Indo-European idiom. Bringing that in line is difficult and it doesn't really get easier with *hora*. Now I should add that I had *even* fresh on my mind because of a ELU question about *even the odds* and *fairness*; Note *hor-* also appears in words about *chance, fairness* and being *lucky*. I don't think the cross correlation looks accidental. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 2):

*Hanc hodie*, literally "this today", is already attested in Plautus's time: the *ho-* element in *hodie* (originally a form of *hic* "this") had gotten semantically bleached until it was no longer emphatic, so an extra form of *hic* was added to get proper emphasis ("on **this** day!").

Loss of `/h/`, similarly, happened very early on: by the first century BCE we have poets mocking hypercorrect pronunciations that add `[h]` in the wrong places, which we wouldn't expect to see if it were still pronounced.

For the semantic development, I'd compare Italian *ancora* and its relatives, originally from Latin *hanc hōram* "this hour" but eventually coming to mean "still, yet, again, more, even". It has various cognates across the Romance languages, including English "encore" (borrowed from French), implying that the shift had already happened in Vulgar Latin. Italian *anco* (later *anche*) and Dalmatian *anca* might come from clippings of this, or from a parallel development in *hanc hodie*; the results are the same either way.

I don't find the proposed Turkish connection nearly as convincing. For one, the Turkish word is pronounced broadly `[and͡ʒak]`, while the Dalmatian was broadly `[aŋka]`; the Turkish also emphasizes one thing happening *in spite of* another, while the Romance emphasizes one thing happening *along with* another. I don't speak Farsi, nor have I been able to find any information on a Farsi word "anja", so I can't comment on that one.

Comment: The French also emphasizes one thing happening again *after it stopped*, while the romance emphasizes *one thing happening along with another*. I'm updating the question with a link to *anja*.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to translate the reference, and hope for downvotes and corrections if I had anything wrong

Original from [2004-2008 Francesco Bonomi - Vocabolario Etimologico della Lingua Italiana](http://www.etimo.it/?term=anche)

> ***anche, anco*** sembra ad alcuni troncato
>
> dal *prov.* ANCUI (*a.fr* `encui`, *dial.lomb.*
>
> `encoi`) che significo *quest'oggi*, dal *lat.*
>
> HANC-HODIE; altri lo tratto dal *lat.*
>
> (AD)HANC sottinteso HORAM, d'onde la voce
>
> *ancora*, sebbene faccia difficolta il tronca-
>
> mento specialmente della *partic.* AD, della
>
> quale non sembra possa farsi  a meno, come
>
> nol si potrebbe dell' IN nella espressione IN
>
> QUESTA per *in questa contingenza*; e final-
>
> mente, come inclinerebbe a ritenere il
>
> Diez, riprovato dal Körting, vuolsi deri-
>
> vato dal *lat.* ADHUC *ancora*, *inoltre* med-
>
> iante le forme AUC, AUNC, ANC, da cui
>
> pure il *rtr*. AUNC. -- Particella che ora e
>
> copulativa, corrrispondante ad Ancora,
>
> Exiandio; talora e avverbio e vale Molto,
>
> Benissimo, Certamente ecc.

My translation does make and less sense towarda the end. From the second sentence on I am way uncertain.

> ***anche, anco*** resembles a short truncation
>
> of *prov.* [provoncial] ANCUI (*a.fr.* [ancient French] `encui`, *dial.lomb.* [dialectal Lombardic / Lombardic dialect]
>
> `ancoi`) which means *quest'oggi* ["today", Det.+"today"?], from Latin
>
> HANC-HODIE; Others want to treat it as from Latin
>
> (AD)HANC with HORAM implied, giving the word
>
> *ancora*, although not without problems,
>
> especially from the riddance of the *partic*. [particle] AD,
>
> which in no other instance comes to mind, just
>
> as much as the particle IN is not omitted in IN
>
> QUESTA for example *in questa condizione* "under what condition"; And final-
>
> ly, as inclined as is Diez, following Körting, to think of deriving from ADHUC: *ancora*, *inoltre* via
>
> the forms AUC, AUNC, ANC, whence
>
> also *rtr*. [Retoromanic=Aromanian] AUNC. -- Particles of
>
> time being copula, corresponding to Ancora,
>
> do exist; Sometimes they are adverbs and expressing variously agreement or certainty.

Comment: Also "Uncuò" in the Veneto dialect.